# Do you know a free test data generator for mysql database?

Tags: mysql, database

Do you know a free test data generator for mysql database?

Maybe native tools allow you to generate test data?

Comment: i have found this one http://filldb.info/dbgenerator, you can import your schema.

Answer (score 17):

You could try [GenerateData.com](http://www.generatedata.com). It lets you quickly generate large volumes of custom data (Name, Adress, Phone number, random number, random text...) in a variety of formats (csv, xml, excel, mysql, oracle).

**Edit:** If you don't want to install it, there is an [online generator](http://www.generatedata.com/#generator) that allows you to generate data up to 5000 rows.

Comment: You could use the online generator.

Comment: Online you can generate up to 5000 recs. Not bad.

Comment: +1 for  "online generator"

Comment: it generate only 100 records !

Answer (score 4):

I've come across this one generator.
May be useful:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/spawner/